# App enters background determine current ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, notifications

I am currently working on an iOS app and want to add a notification to the notification center if and only if the user was looking at a certain view controller when they left the app.  The app has a count down timer and if they are looking at the count down timer and go to send a text or any other app I would like to send a notification once the timer is at 0.  But if they were on another view controller I have no need to send a notification.  Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Within the `UIViewController` that you wish to detect the app going to background you are going to need to register for the `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` and `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification` notifications with `NSNotificationCenter` when `viewWillAppear` is called.

```
NSNotificationCenter .defaultCenter() .addObserver(self, selector: Selector("callBack"), name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter .defaultCenter() .addObserver(self, selector: Selector("callBack"), name: UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification, object: nil)
```

When this screen calls back to your method handling the notification, schedule your `UILocalNotification` to trigger at the current time, plus the timer count. You can use `init(timeIntervalSinceNow:)` on `NSDate` for this.

```
var fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 25)

var localNotification = UILocalNotification()

localNotification.fireDate = fireDate

UIApplication .sharedApplication() .scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

And then remove the `UIViewController` as an observer.

```
NSNotificationCenter .defaultCenter() .removeObserver(self)
```